$\|f^{-1} \|= \frac{1}{a} $
We define
$$B(X,Y)= \{ f \mid f:X \to Y, \text{ is continuous and linear function}\}$$
Let $X,Y$ bee Banach normed spaces, $f \in B(X,Y)$, $a>0$, and $ \|f(x)\| \ge a\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$.
Then

$f:X \to f(X) $ is a bijective.

$f(X)$ is closed and $f^{-1} \in B(f(X),X)$

$\|f^{-1} \|= \frac{1}{a} $


I have proved number one and two.
But I can't prove 3)
I tried like this:
for $f^{-1} (x)$ we know that $ x\in f(X) \subset Y \text{ and }  f^{-1} (x) \in X$
then from question
$\|x\| \ge a\|f^{-1} (x)\| \Rightarrow \|f^{-1} (x)\| \le a^{-1} \|x\| \Rightarrow \|f^{-1} \| \le \frac{1}{a} $
But I can't prove that $ \|f^{-1} \| \ge \frac{1}{a} $
also, I have a question about number 2; for proving that $f(X)$ is closed can I say that it is closed because it is isomorph with $\ker f$ when ker f is closed here. ( Here $ \ker f={0}$)

As stated, 3. is false. For you don't specify $a$ uniquely; if you start with some $a$ as you state, you may replace it with $a/2$ for instance and you still have it satisfying the same properties.
If you put $a=\sup\{c:\ \|f(x)\|\geq c\|x\|,\ x\in X\}$, then fix $\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\d{\delta}\d>0$ and choose $x\in X$ such that $a\|x\|\geq (1-\delta)\|f(x)\|$. Then
\begin{align}
\|f^{-1}(f(x))\|=\|x\|\geq\frac{1-\delta}a\,\|f(x)\|.
\end{align}
So $\|f^{-1}\|\geq\frac{1-\delta}a$ for all $\delta>0$ and so $\|f^{-1}\|\geq\frac1a$.

I have a question about number 2; for proving that $f(X)$ is closed can I say that it is closed because it is isomorph with ker $f$ when ker f is closed here. ( Here $ ker f={0})

But it is not isomorphic to $\ker f$; you have $\ker f=\{0\}$ and $f(X)$ is not $\{0\}$ unless $f=0$. In any case, even if you could argue like that you have to be careful because you want "isomorphism" in the sense of "homeomorphism", otherwise closedness would not be necessarily preserved.
The way to prove that $f(X)$ is closed is direct: let $\{f(x_n)\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $f(X)$. Since
$$
\|x_n-x_m\|\leq\frac1a\|f(x_n-x_m)\|=\frac1a\,\|f(x_n)-f(x_m)\|, 
$$
you deduce that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. As $X$ is complete, there exists $x\in X$ with $x=\lim_nx_n$. And as $f$ is bounded, $f(x)=\lim f(x_n)$, so $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges and hence $f(X)$ is closed.

yes, f(X) is isomorph with X/ker f not with ker f. I forgot. I'm sorry. I got the point thank you so much

Glad I could help. Please upvote if you found the answer useful.
